# Can Geda hook right into Spring Conversion Service?

Tags: java, spring, dozer, orika

Like Dozer or Orika, can Geda be hooked into the Spring Conversion Service? I want the ability to have the abstraction of bean mappers and our code looks like the following:

```
@Service
public class TestDAOImpl {
   @Autowired
   private ConversionService conversionService;
   @Autowired
   private ITestService service;

   public EntityDTO save(final EntityDTO entityDTO) {
      // Can Geda be abstracted like this? Currently using Dozer underneath
      // Converts our DTO to the database entity
      Entity entity = conversionService.convert(entityDTO, Entity.class);
      entity = service.save(entity);
      return conversionService.convert(entity, EntityDTO.class);
   }
}
```

Currently I am using Dozer but it is too slow when dealing with large collections. I tested Orika and it was a lot faster but was slower than Dozer with small collections. I heard Geda was faster than both Dozer and Orika, but my only concern is I am not sure if it can be abstracted like Dozer and Orika as shown in the pseudocode above.

Answer (score 0):

Orika is lot faster, but has a little overhead in startup time, you should not trust naive benchmark, there is lot of thing to concider when it comes to write a real benchmark: cleaning GC, jvm warm-up, .... 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/